# how to add custom message in contact form 7 programmatically

Tags: php, contact-form-7

I'm not able to send the custom message in the email body before sending it in contact form 7 programmatically.

this is the code that I wrote in the functions.php

```php
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail', 'my_custom_contact_form_7_mail_function', 10, 2 );

function my_custom_contact_form_7_mail_function( $contact_form, $email ) {
  // Get the contact form fields.
  $contact_form_fields = $contact_form->get_posted_data();

  // Create a custom message.
  $custom_message = 'This is my custom message.';
  $custom_message .= ' ' . $field_name . ': ' . $field_value;
  

  // Append the custom message to the email body.
  $email['body'] = str_replace("[custom-message]", "$custom_message");
}
```

this is my contact form 7 mail settings:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. `wpcf7_mail` does not even seem to be something you could hook into. You probably want to use a `filter` rather than an `action` on `wpcf7_mail_components`.
2. What do you need `$contact_form_fields` for? It's never been used!
3. Your function uses `$field_name` and `$field_value`, but you didn't define these variables.
4. `str_replace` accepts either three or four arguments, never just two. It's `search`, `replace`, `subject`.
5. The arguments for the function aren't `by reference`, so you need to return the new value.

This should be working:

```
function my_wpcf7_mail_components($components, $form, $mail_object) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    // Get the contact form fields.
    $contact_form_fields = $submission->get_posted_data();

    // Create a custom message.
    $custom_message = 'This is my custom message.';
    $custom_message .= ' ' . $contact_form_fields['your-name'] . ' has sent you a message.';

    // Append the custom message to the email body.
    $components['body'] = str_replace("[custom-message]", $custom_message, $components['body']);
    return $components;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'my_wpcf7_mail_components', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: You are very welcome. Please make sure to accept this answer if it helped you and might be of help to others.